# What does checkpointing do on Apache Spark?

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, pyspark, checkpointing

What does checkpointing do for Apache Spark, and does it take any hits on RAM or CPU?

Comment: What do you not understand from reading the documentation? http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/streaming-programming-guide.html#checkpointing

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between spark checkpoint and persist to a disk](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35127720/what-is-the-difference-between-spark-checkpoint-and-persist-to-a-disk)

Answer (score 1):

From Apache Streaming [Documentation](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/streaming-programming-guide.html#checkpointing) - Hope it helps:

A streaming application must operate 24/7 and hence must be resilient to failures unrelated to the application logic (e.g., system failures, JVM crashes, etc.). For this to be possible, Spark Streaming needs to checkpoint enough information to a fault- tolerant storage system such that it can recover from failures. There are two types of data that are checkpointed.

- Metadata checkpointing - Saving of the information defining the
  streaming computation to fault-tolerant storage like HDFS. This is
  used to recover from failure of the node running the driver of the
  streaming application (discussed in detail later). Metadata includes:

  - Configuration - The configuration that was used to create the
    streaming application.
  - DStream operations - The set of DStream
    operations that define the streaming application.
  - Incomplete batches
  - Batches whose jobs are queued but have not completed yet.
- Data checkpointing - Saving of the generated RDDs to reliable    storage.    This is necessary in some stateful transformations that    combine data    across multiple batches. In such transformations, the    generated RDDs    depend on RDDs of previous batches, which causes    the length of the    dependency chain to keep increasing with time.    To avoid such    unbounded increases in recovery time (proportional    to dependency    chain), intermediate RDDs of stateful    transformations are    periodically checkpointed to reliable storage    (e.g. HDFS) to cut off    the dependency chains.

To summarize, metadata checkpointing is primarily needed for recovery from driver failures, whereas data or RDD checkpointing is necessary even for basic functioning if stateful transformations are used.