# Apache Spark slows down on doing lots of transforms without any actions

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a spark.sql.Dataframe with various columns, and I perform different transformation steps on its columns. Only at the end there is an action (write to parquet).

I have been noticing that Spark gets slower and slower, while the "stack" of transforms builds up. Eventually I also run [into an OutOfMemoryError](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43637913/6699237).

To circumvent this I have tried:

- **persist**: a `persist()` in between the transformation steps did not help.
- **temporary parquet files**: curiously this DID work: by writing a parquet after a number of transformations, `del`ing the `df` and reading the parquet files up again, the speed was back to "normal"

Thus my question(s):

- Am I doing something wrong?
- Has anybody encountered similar problems? How did you solve it?
- Is it "good practice" to save intermediary results (temporarily) to disk and load them up again (I thought not b/c executors can spill to disk if necessary)?

### EDIT 2017-05-04

sorry, here is some code:

#### Example 1: value-based row filtering

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
df = df.where((F.col('col') > max_value ) | (F.col('col') < min_value ))
```

#### Example 2: dropping duplicates based on certain columns

```
list_of_cols = ['col1', 'col2', ...]
df = df.dropDuplicates(list_of_cols)
```

#### Example 3: replace values below threshold with 0

```
df = df.withColumn('col', F.when(condition, new_value).otherwise(F.col('col')))
```

#### Example 4: detect decreasing parts of a colum that should be strictly increasing

(a strictly increasing `id` column permits this check)

```
    id_win = (Window
              .partitionBy('group_col')
              .orderBy('id')
              )
    inc_win = (Window
                .partitionBy('group_col')
                .orderBy('strictly_inc_col')
                )

    bad_rows = (df
                 .select('group_col', 'id',
                         F.row_number().over(id_win).alias('order_id'),
                         F.row_number().over(inc_win).alias('order_inc'))
                 .where('order_inc < order_id')
                 .select('id')
                 .toDF('id')
                 )

    df = (df
          .join(bad_rows, 'id', 'left_outer')
          .where(bad_rows['id'].isNull())
          .select(df.columns)
          )
```

#### Example 5: Check for lots of missing values

see [OutOfMemoryError Post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43637913/6699237) for the code, as it is quite long...

### EDIT 2017-05-18

I found out about Spark's `pyspark.sql.DataFrame.checkpoint` method. [This is like `persist` but gets rid of the dataframe's lineage](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35130205/6699237). Thus it helps to circumvent the above mentioned issues.

Comment: "Am I doing something wrong?" Please share your code, we can't tell you what's wrong if we don't know what is doing

Comment: sorry, added some code