# OutOfMemoryError on Spark's driver - heap dump 1Gb while 10Gb is configured

Tags: java, apache-spark, out-of-memory

I have a 100% reproductible `OutOfMemoryError` (most often due to a GC overhead limit exceeded) when running my Spark application. That happens approximately on the 700th stage.

As the error stack always includes classes like `.ui.`, `TaskSchedulerImpl`, etc., I've concluded that **the problem lies not in executors, but in the driver process** itself.
This conclusion is backed up by the following observation: minutes before the OOM, the `stdout` output starts pausing for a second or so, printing lots of lines momentarily immediately after the pause.

**`spark.driver.memory` is configured to be 10G, but the debugging tools used show that only 1Gb is used by the driver:**

1. I've used these [great instructions](https://anish749.github.io/spark/analyzing-java-garbage-collection-logs-debugging-optimizing-apache-spark/) on collecting GC statistics and analyzing it with the [gceasy.io](http://gceasy.io) service; it clearly showed that:

   - The maximum heap usage after GC is approximately 1Gb.
   - Close to the moment of OOM, the 'heap usage' graph almost touches the maximum of 1Gb, and the numerous GC events fail to affect that. `GC overhead limit exceeded` at its best.
2. I've used the [MAT](https://www.eclipse.org/mat/) to analyse the heap dump created immediately after the OutOfMemoryError.

   - The heap dump contains approximately the same 1Gb of data.
   - Dominator tree shows that more than half of that is consumed by UI objects.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32271731/why-is-my-java-heap-dump-size-much-smaller-than-used-memory)'s answer suggests that the 10Gb-1Gb=9Gb may be used by JNI libraries; but apparently the Spark does not use that at it's core; neither am I.

I've used [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43637913/apache-spark-outofmemoryerror-heapspace)'s answer to minimize the UI data retained. As a result, my application runned succesfully. **But i am not ready to part with all the precious debugging data that can be explored using the Spark UI.**

Also, I was not able to find any explanation of the Spark's driver memory model.

**The question is: how fo I retain UI debugging data and do not run into OOMs on my driver?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The actual problem was that only 1Gb of memory was used by driver process, despite the setting `spark.driver.memory=10G`.

According to [documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/configuration.html): **in client mode, this config** (spark.driver.memory) **must not be set through the SparkConf directly in your application, because the driver JVM has already started at that point. Instead, please set this through the --driver-memory command line option or in your default properties file.**

I was using the client mode. Moving the setting from Spark context parameter to spark-submit command line parameter solved the issue.

P.S. "If nothing works as expected, read the manual" (c).