# Pyspark Fetch Failed Exception in count

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, timeout, shuffle

I have a Shuffle Exception with a count, I need help, this is the error:

```
21/12/17 11:01:47 INFO DAGScheduler: Job 20 failed: count at /home/spark/jobs.zip/tca/jobs/participation_on_volume_metric/participation_on_volume_metric_job.py:388, took 1283.109346 s
21/12/17 11:01:47 INFO DAGScheduler: Resubmitting ShuffleMapStage 130 (leftOuterJoin at /home/spark/jobs.zip/tca/jobs/participation_on_volume_metric/participation_on_volume_metric_job.py:261) and ShuffleMapStage 132 (leftOuterJoin at /home/spark/jobs.zip/tca/jobs/participation_on_volume_metric/participation_on_volume_metric_job.py:277) due to fetch failure
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/spark/pywrap.py", line 53, in <module>
    app.run(main=main, argv=[sys.argv[0]] + unparsed)
  File "/home/spark/jobs.zip/tca/platform/app.py", line 20, in run
  File "/home/spark/libs.zip/absl/app.py", line 300, in run
  File "/home/spark/libs.zip/absl/app.py", line 251, in _run_main
  File "/home/spark/pywrap.py", line 32, in main
    job.analyze(spark_context, arguments, {'config': job_conf})
  File "/home/spark/jobs.zip/tca/jobs/participation_on_volume_metric/participation_on_volume_metric_job.py", line 388, in analyze
  File "/home/spark/libs.zip/pyspark/rdd.py", line 1055, in count
  File "/home/spark/libs.zip/pyspark/rdd.py", line 1046, in sum
  File "/home/spark/libs.zip/pyspark/rdd.py", line 917, in fold
  File "/home/spark/libs.zip/pyspark/rdd.py", line 816, in collect
  File "/home/spark/libs.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1257, in __call__
  File "/home/spark/libs.zip/py4j/protocol.py", line 328, in get_return_value
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling z:org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.collectAndServe.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: A shuffle map stage with indeterminate output was failed and retried. However, Spark cannot rollback the ShuffleMapStage 132 to re-process the input data, and has to fail this job. Please eliminate the indeterminacy by checkpointing the RDD before repartition and try again.
```

It failed in the count after rdd unions:

```
orders_metric_rdd = sc.union([orders_with_mic_metric_rdd, \
        orders_with_childs_metric_rdd, \
        orders_without_childs_metric_rdd])
        
    orders_metric_rdd.cache()

    partitions = max(1, orders_metric_rdd.count())
    partitions = min(partitions, max_partitions)
```

Answer (score 0):

From the error log it looks like you need to add a checkpoint. You can do so like this.

```
orders_metric_rdd = sc.union([orders_with_mic_metric_rdd, \
        orders_with_childs_metric_rdd, \
        orders_without_childs_metric_rdd])
        
sc.setCheckpointDir("/tmp/checkpoint_dir/")
orders_metric_rdd.checkpoint()

partitions = max(1, orders_metric_rdd.count())
partitions = min(partitions, max_partitions)
```

Comment: Can you explain to me the checkpoint concept, thank you

Comment: Basically a checkpoint saves the RDD in memory. It is essentially a breakpoint in the execution plan. You might find this discussion helpful -> [Checkpoint vs Persist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35127720/what-is-the-difference-between-spark-checkpoint-and-persist-to-a-disk)